# Interpreter won't show in Python 3.8.1

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

I recently downloaded python for the first time and when I load into pycharm to create a new project and it asks to select an interpreter python doesn't show up even when I click the plus sign and search through all my files it doesn't show even though I have the latest python version installed and I have windows 10 I tried deleting both programs and redownloading them but that doesn't seem to work either please if possible and the answer may be obvious but sorry I'm a beginner and also looking at videos didn't help either.

Comment: With the add button you can normally navigate to the folder where Python is installed. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments?

Answer (score 2):

You have no navigate to the folder where python is downloaded and just select there.
Try the following path C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe